# CreateObject("WScript.Shell") is Nothing error

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I have a script below:

```
Dim g_oWShell 
Set g_oWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

But when I validate the value of `g_oWShell` first, that object is null (nothing). Below are the codes I'm debugging:

```
If g_oWShell Is Nothing Then
    'display an error. 
Else
    'run Something... (Ex. g_oWShell.Run("...")
End If
```

I'm new to VBS and I'm not sure why is that the case. I have read a short definition of `CreateObject` method here: [VBA CreateObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609975/vba-createobject)

Advance thanks for explaining what might I have missed.

**EDIT:**

I'm creating an MSI installer using Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Actually its not an error. I just made an if else and if g_oWShell is nothing, it will show me some error I made, because obviously .Run("...") won't work if the object is nothing. It's just a validation... Sorry if it's confusing..

Comment: How are you validating the "value" of g_oWShell? What do you mean by value of an object exactly? Your code should run fine.

Comment: As Kira said, this code should run fine, provided that the CreateObject and your If condition are in the same scope. E.g. same Function or SubRoutine.